# Ignoring a directory chain in git?

Tags: git, file, ignore, gitignore, glob

I need to ignore the following.

In paths like `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g`, I need to ignore `/d/e/f/g`. I also need to be able to ignore every place `/d/e/f/g` appears beneath `a`. I tried `d/e/f/g`, but that did not work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
**/d/e/f/g
```

or:

```
a/**/d/f/g
```

Answer (score 5):

Interesting requirement. I'm curious what your use case actually is.

The way you *should* do something like this is a separate `.gitignore` in the parent directory of each sub-tree you need to exclude (git reads all the `.gitignore` files on its way down the tree).

If you *really want* a single `.gitignore` file... Well, I haven't tried this, but going by the [gitignore doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), it's mostly a typical shell glob, so what *might* work is something like:

```
a/*/d/e/f/g
a/*/*/d/e/f/g
a/*/*/*/d/e/f/g
```

... repeating with an ever-increasing number of asterisks out to the deepest you expect it to reasonably go.

I imagine there will be a performance penalty here, but I don't know how serious. Probably not noticeable for most repos on any system built in the last 5-10 years.